# Control multi-page html input/output with Vite

Tags: html, vite, bundling-and-minification, multipage

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a vite config to achieve the following input/output structure:

```
/views/home/home.template.html
/views/about/about.template.html
```

I have my html files like above with their specific JS / CSS imports.

```
{out_dir}/home/home.html
{out_dir}/home/js/*.bundle.js
{out_dir}/home/css/*.bundle.css
{out_dir}/about/about.html
```

And above is how I'd like the output to look. Essentially I want to transform (for ex. home page) from `views/home/home.template.html` -> `{out_dir}/home/home.html` and have their JS/CSS imports bundled under "js" / "css" sub directories.

Is there a config option or any plugins I can use to achieve this?